# add file to multiple file upload form

Tags: javascript, upload

I have a basic multiple file upload form like :
`<input id="file_input" type="file" multiple/>`

When the user clicks "browse...", a Windows OS popup opens (file explorer), the user selects 3 files then clicks "Open". Popup closes, the browser's file input says "3 files selected", the user is ready to click "Submit" in order to upload the files. So far so good.

How do I make it so that the user can ADD more files to this list of 3, without him having to select all the files again, in case he missed some files initially?
The default browser behavior when the user clicks "Browse..." again is to wipe all the selected files initially picked.

Kindly note that I do NOT want to use an existing library, but pure javascript. I know there are countless jquery scripts or github repos searching for "multiple file upload".

I did not fine anything related to this on the MDN docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications
or here : https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI

Right now I'm thinking about a dirty solution such as dynamically generating a new upload form in the DOM when the user clicks "Browse..." (or an "add more files" button). There must be more elegant solutions, right?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that. This is not something JavaScript has any direct control over. Either the file selection dialog retains the old list or it doesn't.

Comment: @Barmar this one can do it plupload[.]com/examples/ I haven't looked at its source code yet to understand the trick

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just add the files dinamically? use a "plus" or "add more files"button to add more input type="file" and upload as many files as you wish?

Comment: @ChrisG This is the dirty solution I suggested in my post. I'm looking for a more clever implementation before resigning to it.

Comment: @Musa is the solution you are looking for necessary tho? you could save time going for the easy one